# receceive unexpected output in calculation

Tags: java, output

I am trying to write a java program that allows the user to convert the given temp in fahrenheit then converts the given temp to celsius, however I am having a problem when I input the temp 95.35 fahrenheit it converts it to 35.19 ,when the expected output should be 35.20.

```
        System.out.println("Enter Body Temperature (In F):\n");
        double tempF = scan.nextDouble();
        double tempFRound = tempF / 100.00;
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        String tempFahrenheit = decimalFormat.format(tempFRound * 100) + 'F';
        double tempC = ((tempF - 32) * (5 / 9.0)) / 100.0;
        double tempCRound = tempC * 100.00;
        String tempCelsius = decimalFormat.format(tempCRound) + 'C';
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("Vitals: %s|%s|" , tempFahrenheit , tempCelsius );
```

Comment: When use a calculator, I get 35.194444. So, what is wrong with 35.19? That appears to be the correct answer.

Comment: What's with all the `/ 100` and `* 100`?